# Get an object attribute of a model in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a class called Employee. An Employee has a IManager object as a property like this:

```cs
public class Employee : IManagable{
(...)
public IManager ManagedBy
        {get; set;}
(...)
}
```

This is my Manager class that implements the IManager interface

```cs
    public class Manager : IManager, IManagable
    {
(...)
        public string FirstName
        {get; set}
       

        public string LastName
        {get; set}
(...)
    }
```

Now I want to list a bunch of information with the help of the View code below.

```html
@model IEnumerable<LibraryApplication.Models.Domain.Employee.Employee>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManagedBy)
        </td>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ManagedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

If I want to access an attribute of the manager, what can I do? I've tried this: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ManagedBy.FirstName)` to add the first name of the manager in the table but it throws this error

> System.ArgumentException: 'The property LibraryApplication.Models.Domain.Employee.IManager.FirstName could not be found

When i just do this `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ManagedBy)` it lists all the properties for the manager like below, which is not relevant in this case.
[image]

what can i do?

The IManager interface is this simple interface:

```cs
    public interface IManager : IEmployee
    {
    }
```

(it will declare other methods in the future)

and this is my IEmployee interface:

```cs
namespace LibraryApplication.Models.Domain.Employee
{
    public interface IEmployee
    {
        int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        double Salary
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        bool IsCEO
        {
            get;
        }

        bool IsManager
        {
            get;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, the Manager has a FirstName property so I can easily reference it. But why can't i do it in my View file?

**EDIT**
Now I can make it work in 2 different ways. Either I change the `ManagedBy` property to `Manager` instead of `IManager`. OR i add the following to my `IManager` interface:

```cs
public IManager ManagedBy
        {get; set;}
```

It works both ways. But why do i have to declare `ManagedBy` in `IManager` as well if I already declare it in the `IEmployee` interface that `IManager` implements?

Comment: could you display the class IManager

Comment: sure, i added it to the original post.

Comment: Why in lambda for `DisplayFor` your variable is `modelItem` and in body use use `item` ?

Comment: Because it is a part of the loop. item is each item in a list to be displayed. i'll add the code for the view in my post.

Comment: Seems like the `FirstName` is missing from the `IManager` interface. Please share the `IManager` interface to make sure what the problem is.

Comment: Firstname makes part of Manager not IManager

Comment: @Frenchy It worked! but why can't i just use IManager.ManagedBy? when referencing to the property like that it has worked before, does it work differently in .cshtml files?

Comment: you have to modify your logic of interface... all persons are employee, some employee are manager. and all employees have a manager

Answer (score 1):

you should use manager mangedby instead of Imanager

```
public class Employee : IManagable{
(...)
public Manager ManagedBy
        {get; set;}
(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to review your logic:

```
  manager is also an employee, so you could derive Manager from IEmployee

  you specify in Interface IManager, what is just needed for managers
```